# Sound problem with Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: sound

After a clean install alongside windows 10, I find out my laptop's sound not working correctly. No sound in speakers and 3.5 jack.

The model is ASUS UX430UNR

When I tried this:

sudo alsactl restore

I got this:

alsactl: load_state:1683: Cannot open /var/lib/alsa/asound.state for reading: No such file or directory
Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Realtek ALC294" "HDA:10ec0294,10431c20,00100004 HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000" "0x1043" "0x1c20"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method

And now something weird happening, some boop boop coming from the headset and after a while music sound coming from speakers but muting after 3 sec.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Ok! after wasting my weekend over this I find out I need to shut down windows first (not restart) then start ubuntu. I don't know what's going on there but this will fix the problem :/

Comment: Have you disabled *fast startup* in Windows? Perhaps this is the problem.